# asus_nb_wmi - wifi and mobile brandband

Tags: wireless, 14.04, mobile-broadband

I have asus x550v and I have problem with ubuntu 14.04.
When set to asus_nb_wmi:
0 - wifi not working but mobile brandband working.
1 - wifi working but mobile brandband not working.
4 - wifi working but mobile brandband not working.

How I must set it? where is problem?

Comment: FN + F2 - did not work.

Comment: The various values for asus_nb_wmi are not well documented. I would try every number from 0 to 9 and if you find success, report back. You might also try with the module removed altogether: sudo modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi.

Comment: hmm

rm /etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf
modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi

wait 10-20 second and it works.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that removing *asus-nb-wmi* allows both wireless and mobile broadband to work as expected. I suggest you blacklist it:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist asus-nb-wmi"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r asus-nb-wmi
exit
```

You should be all set.